# Output C# Function to DocumentDB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

this might be me not being overly awesome at C# (I'm getting there) or the documentation for this not being overly complete.

Anyways, I'm trying to get some Azure Events and then write each event to DocumentDB.

```
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, out ICollector<string> outputDocument)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        JArray auditLogs = GetAuditLogsJArray(TenantId, AuditApiVersion, log);

        outputDocument = null;
        foreach (dynamic logevent in auditLogs)
        {
            object document = new
            {
                id = logevent.id,
                activityType = logevent.activityType,    
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
            outputDocument.Add(json);
        }
    }
```

I am constantly getting a `System.NullReferenceException` on the last line and I don't know why. 
Visual Studio debugging shows me that json has a value (a json string).
If I change the code to not be an `ICollector` but just a `string` and change the last line to 
`outputDocument = json;`
then the Function completes and adds only one document to DocumentDB, not ALL of them (almost 500).

What am I doing wrong?!

Cheers
David

Comment: You're initializing `outputDocument` to null just above the loop. That's why when you call `Add` you're getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I think. What should I initialise it to though, @GauravMantri ?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea :). Some kind of collection may be?

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with. If I take that line away then Visual Studio won't build my solution because of an unassigned out parameter.
Leave it in, see above. WIll test a bit more, thanks so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, ICollector<string> outputDocument)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    JArray auditLogs = GetAuditLogsJArray(TenantId, AuditApiVersion, log);

    // outputDocument = null;
    // not out-param so it will be passed in.
    foreach (dynamic logevent in auditLogs)
    {
        object document = new
        {
            id = logevent.id,
            activityType = logevent.activityType,    
        };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
        outputDocument.Add(json);
    }
}
```